# How to "Live preview " in PhpStorm and WebStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, development-environment, jetbrains-ide

I need to use "live preview" PhpStorm in Firefox browser but this module cannot be found in PhpStorm.

There is PhpStorm extension for Chrome, but it does not work very well and I'm using just Firefox browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Live Edit](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2020.1/live-editing.html) functionality is only supported in Chrome.
Firefox support can't be expected in the foreseeable future:
to implement the Live Edit functionality, we need to support the Firefox Debugging Protocol from scratch. This requires significant efforts and resources that we are not ready to invest right now. We recommend using tools like [Browsersync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-sync) that we believe provide the great development experience.